# Change persistence.xml in seam test

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, seam, testng

In our production and development we develop against an MSSQL database.

but when we run our test we would like todo it against an HSQL database.

it is no problem to change the DS file so it runs against the HSQL but the old dialcet from persitence.xml is still MSSQL dialect so how do i change it to HSQL dialect?

//Trind

Comment: Are you using Spring framework?

Comment: No i am Using Seam 2.2.2-Final, and we use maven to deploy with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use resource and test resource filtering.

```
<filters>
    <filter>src/main/filters/dev.filter.properties</filter>
    <filter>src/test/filters/dev.filter.properties</filter>
</filters>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Define a hibernate.dialect property in the dev.filter.properties files and make it different in main and test directories.

Then use it the persistence.xml files in test and main.

See

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/testResources-mojo.html

Comment: Does this work when i have diffrent projects for the test and for the project that is being tested?

Comment: If you have 2 separate projects then you can use two separate persistence.xml files each one containing its dialect.